# Heroku , pull sqlite3 database

Tags: node.js, database, git, heroku, sqlite

**Hello everyone**

I am using Heroku to host an app, all seems working (i am using node.js, express.js and sqlite3, all data seems to be updating)

Yesterday i wanted to "download" my database but when I downloaded my database seems to be **outdated** (the version that i downloaded, in fact, **the database that it downloaded is the original database that I uploaded when I create the app**, the changes are not there, **but when I query my database that is online it seems to be updated.**)

I used the following command in order to get the files that are online in my app

```
 heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

Is there a correct way or command in order to get the database that is online?

*Thanks in advance*

I am usign the database that i created with the module of sqlite3:

```
"use strict";

var express = require("express"); 
var app = express(); 
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();  

var bp = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bp.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

var dbiOS = new sqlite3.Database('AppBienestar.db');  //this is the database that I am using. I CREATED
                                                      //THE DATABASE WITH THE SAME METHOD IN ANOTHER FILE.

app.set('views','./views'); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

These are my files that I uploaded in the heroku service

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UucnL.jpg

Ps: sorry If my English is not perfect, English is not my native language.

Comment: I already got the answer, heroku is no the ideal tool for my app, Heroku's git support is effectively one-way; you can use it to push new code to be run on the server, but you can't use it to copy files from Heroku back to your local tree.